# How do I put JSON into a PHP Variable?

Tags: php, html, json

I´m trying to put JSON-Information into a PHP variable and I´m getting Errors all the time.

This is my Code to make the JSON readable:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
print_r ($jsondecode1);
```

This is a snippet of the `$jsondecode1`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [flightId] => ******
            [******] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [******] => ******
                    [******] => ******
                    [******] => ******
                    [******] => ******
                    [******] => ******                
                )
```

Notice: When I `echo` the `jsondecode1` it outputs this:

> Array to string conversion in
>   **C:\xampp......\simpletest3.php** on
>   line **48**

So I used `print_r()`.

What I tried to put (for example) `[flightId]` into a PHP Variable:

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
$jsondecode2 = $jsondecode1->flightId;
print_r ($jsondecode2);
```

> Output: **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'flightId' of non-object in **C:.........\simpletest3.php** on line **48**

I tried some other codes too, but the Outputs were very similar and I don´t want to make my Question longer than it needs to be.
So, how do I put (for example) the `[flightId]` into a PHP variable.

**Edit:**

> Solution:

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
$jsondecode2 = $jsondecode1[0]->flightId;
print_r ($jsondecode2);
```

> Or:

```
foreach ($jsondecode1 as $data) {
    print_r($data->flightId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You have to do it like below (what you shown)***

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
$jsondecode2 = $jsondecode1[0]->flightId;
echo $jsondecode2;
```

***But you have multi-dimensional-array,so do like below:-***

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);

foreach ($jsondecode1 as $jsondecode) {
    echo $jsondecode->flightId; // here you can use echo $flightId = $jsondecode->flightId; 
}
```

Comment: @duffbeerisgood  also when you used `json_decode()` it converts the json string into object array

Comment: @duffbeerisgood  for the current scenario, yes, as you want to iterate over json data and try to get the values form it.

Answer (score 2):

Your json contains an array of objects, not 1 object.

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);

// loop through all objects in the array
foreach ($jsondecode1 as $data) {
    print_r($data->flightId);
}
```

Or if you only want to have the first object of the array:

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
$jsondecode2 = $jsondecode1[0]->flightId;
print_r ($jsondecode2);
```

But then the question is why is the json an array and not a single object?

---

Also you can not simply echo or print out non-scalar types (like arrays or objects), for that you will have to use `print_r`.

Comment: Great Solution. Thank you !

Comment: I have no Idea why the json is an array, I thought you guys could tell me that.

Comment: @duffbeerisgood That is your input, so I can not tell you why it is like that :) $json1 is a string containing something like [{"flightId": "******", ...}]. That is an array of objects. If it were to have {"flightId": "******", ...}, without the [ and ] around it, it's a single json object.

Answer (score 2):

Your `flightId` is inside one array whoch index is `0`. So you have to first access that array then you can get `flightId`

try below code:

```
$jsondecode1 = json_decode($json1);
$jsondecode2 = $jsondecode1[0]->flightId;
print_r ($jsondecode2);
```